# php&mysql search mysql table while rendering output from another table

Tags: php, css, mysql

I have MYSQL table1 with columns (id(primary key), name, location, type)
and table2 with columns (table1id(relation), confirmation(int(1 or 2))

now what I would like to do is the following .
I want to get data from table1 and render it to HTML table (I can do that easly)
my problem is the following .
I want to give each HTML Table row a CSS class according to it's confirmation status from table2 .

I hope I could explain what i want in a correct way .

Comment: could you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: seems pretty straightforward. just do it like how you have explained it

Comment: I tried to get the data from the table2 by writing a mysql query inside the while loop but it seems it is not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have two tables with related data, commonly you use a `JOIN` statement to get a result with the stuff from both tables. You can read about it here: [JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). The MySQL docs can be hard to read at first, but if you're planning on using the database you should get started learning to read the docs as well.

In your case, it would be something like:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.confirmation FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1id
```

There are different ways to join tables; this example will not return a result unless there is a row in table2 that matches the row in table1.

If you take a look at your result from that, you will see that your result has data from both tables.

When you render it, you just need to tweak your current code to add a class to each row. Inside the loop you use for rendering, just add a bit to each row:

```
$output .= '<tr class="' . ($resultRow->confirmation == 1 ? 'confirmed' : 'unconfirmed') . '">';
$output .= [whatever you currently render into the row];
$output .= '</tr>';
```

Obviously since you didn't post any code I can't really guess what your rendering loop looks like, but hopefully you can adapt what I wrote to match your style.

Comment: Hello Jerry
Thank you for reply but join will not solve my problem because it return only the rows which have relation in table2 i want to get all rows from table1 and  just highlight some rows according to it's confirmation status .

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` then. That will give you a row in your result for every row in the table on the left.

Comment: you saved me Jerry .
although I used the LEFT JOIN before in my script but it was not work after your repaly I wrote the query inside the phpmyadmin and it works fine so i rewrite it inside the script and everything works ok now .
thank you very much for your kind help ,